# Boundedness of multivariable polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

How can we prove multivariable polynomials are bounded on a closed set? the boundedness theorem is for single variable functions. Does an extension theorem exist?

Thank you.

Comment: They're not, consider $xy$ on the closed set $\mathbb{R}^2$. I assume you want to show that multivariable polynomials are bounded on compact sets (in $\mathbb{R}^n$, this simply means the set is closed *and* bounded), not on simply closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't in general! If the closed set in question is $\mathbb R^n$, then they are unbounded.

If the set is bounded, you can prove it in the same way for a single variable.

Assume $f$ is not bounded on your closed, bounded (i.e. compact) set $A$. Then for every $n \in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n \in A$ such that $f(x_n) > n$. Then $x_n$ is a bounded sequence, and so it must have a subsequential limit in $A$. Use continuity of $f$ to get a contradiction.